# Tooltip and css transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like the tooltip text to transition in when the mouse is hovered over the tooltip, however I do not want to tooltip text to appear when the mouse is hovered over the space where the tooltip text itself is located.

If 'visibility: hidden' is disabled, the transition is smooth, but the space where tooltip text is located becomes interactable. If 'visibility: hidden' is intact, the transition executes poorly. I would like the transition to work without the space where tooltip text is located responding to hover.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.99;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div class="tooltip">Hover text
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `pointer-events: none;` to your tool-tip element.

I would highly suggest that you use `data-attr` instead, and create a pseudo-element (`::before`) for the tooltip. Less HTML code.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

*[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  inline-block;
}


*[data-tooltip]::before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
   
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
  z-index: 1;
  
  pointer-events: none;
}

*[data-tooltip]:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.99;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="Tooltip text">Hover text</div>
```